# Microsoft advertising ad units with UWP app - Windows 10

Tags: win-universal-app

I've created 2 AdUnits in my Dev Dashboard. One for mobile and one for tablet/pc.

How am I suppose to handle these? I've read so many articles but I've yet to find out anything that tells you how to use both of these? Is that done automatically?

From what I've read and understood, when you upload your app to be approved, it will read the AdMediator.config and update it accordingly but if that's the case, I only have an AdUnit for Microsoft Advertising and one for AdDuplex but nothing that specifies whether it is for mobile or pc/tablets.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Thierry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle AdUnits for Windows Mobile and Tablet/PC, you need to config your `AdMediator.config` file.

#### In `AdMediator.config` following keys are used for Tablet/PC Device family

`WApplicationId` - Tablet/PC Device family Application Id

```
<Key>WApplicationId</Key>
<Value>d25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab</Value>
```

`WAdUnitId` - Tablet/PC Device family AdUnit Id

```
<Key>WAdUnitId</Key>
<Value>10043121</Value>
```

---

#### And following keys are used for Mobile Device family

`MApplicationId` - Mobile Device family Application Id

```
<Key>MApplicationId</Key>
<Value>3f83fe91-d6be-434d-a0ae-7351c5a997f1</Value>
```

`MAdUnitId` - Mobile Device family AdUnit Id

```
<Key>MAdUnitId</Key>
<Value>10865270</Value>
```

---

### Refer the screenshot for any confusion. Hope this is helpful to you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and clarifying this. Do I need to change these manually or will this be done automatically when I upload my app to the store?

Comment: I always do manually, it may be done automatically only if `Id` is same as you created in `dev.windows.com` but I never tried.